# Converting binary data to base64 in Google appscript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, binary, base64

I'm getting an input data in appscript in the form of binary data (docx file data) which looks something like below

[image]

I need this data to be converted into Base64 string. I tried using Utilities class to encode it into base64, however, it returns a few character string which is invalid. Is there any way to convert this form of data in appscript?

The current script is as below

```
function run() { 
var inputData = Eventbus.get('encodedData');//this is received as binary data
var convertedData = Utilities.base64Encode(inputData);//need to encode to base64 but doesn't work
Eventbus.set('decodedData',convertedData);
}
```

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: Can you provide your current script? In your question, I thought that in order to correctly understand your question, it is required to know the method for retrieving `binary data (docx file data) which looks something like below` in your situation. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks for your quick revert. This binary data is retrieved via an Eventbus to the appscript and stored into a variable which in the type string. This is how my script looks like

`function run() {
var inputData = Eventbus.get('encodedData');
var convertedData = Utilities.base64Encode(inputData);
Eventbus.set('decodedData',convertedData);`

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: No, my bad. The comment got added before I complete. Please review my response again.

Comment: `inputData` contains the binary data which I need to convert to base64

Comment: Thank you for replying. In your script, what is `Eventbus`? And, what language are you using now?

Comment: This is google appscript and Eventbus is just a way for me to get the data. The problem is once I get the data, I am unable to convert it to base64. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about `Eventbus`. But I would like to try to understand it. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of the solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Don't worry about the `Eventbus` . Consider the binary data I showed in the above image is stored in variable which needs to be converted into base64

Comment: Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand `Eventbus`.

Comment: Can you edit your quesiton to provide a sample of your original binary data?

Comment: Provide output of `console.log(typeof inputData)` Binary data could mean a lot of things.

Comment: I did try output of typeof inputData and it is String